How do I fix this VersionParser error when migrating a Drupal 10 site to Pantheon?
I'm trying to follow the instructions from https://docs.pantheon.io/guides/drush/drush-import to import a Drupal 10 site to Pantheon. After running the terminus command, I'm getting this error:
[warning] Failed adding and/or installing Drupal 8 dependencies: Failed executing Composer command: The command "'composer' 'require' 'pantheon-systems/drupal-integrations:^' '--no-update'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /home/atlas/pantheon-local-copies/decagon7_terminus_conversion_plugin

Output:
================


Error Output:
================

In VersionParser.php line 519:
                                                                    
  Could not parse version constraint ^: Invalid version string "^"  

Why is it trying to meet Drupal 8 dependencies?? And how do I fix the VersionParser error?
I've tried manually installing pantheon-systems/drupal-integrations, which didn't work. Google results about the VersionParser error seem to be about manual commands. I also tried updating it to 10 with composer (composer.json has it as 9.5 for some reason), which also didn't work

the "carret version range" is missing a version number, it should be ^8 ^9 or ^10

In the composer.json file, is there a module where the version is not numbered or just "ˆ"?
If this is the case, you need to fix the version of this module or library before pushing it to Pantheon.
